# VIMEO API to check when a recurring even is live

Tags: live-streaming, vimeo-api

I want to know if it is possible to check, using API, if a recurring event is actually live at a given moment.

I want to use this to show a visual indicator in the main menu of my website if a user is navigating the site when a livestream is happening, so the user can click and go to watch the live stream. I'm using a WordPress site.

I'm novice on development and would like help form more expert devs!

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Api support for live events available only for Enterprise Users.
To check availability of video or end of event
[This link](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/live/events#managing-a-live-event-step-4) will help you or https://developer.vimeo.com/api/live/events#managing-a-live-event-step-4